# How to add using the same row of data on SQL?

Tags: sql

I am in need of showing the summation of contributions over time; however I would like to demonstrate it using this format.

```
Date Pay  Total
8.1  100  100
8.8  150  250
8.15  50  300
```

So I have only two sets of data, the date and the amount paid. 
I would like to show the change of total amount paid based of the payment amount.

I think I would need to use a subquery but I cannot get it to work for me! 
Any suggestions?

Comment: Please, add data sample and what have you tried so far.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't specify a DBMS so this is ANSI SQL using a window function

```
select date, 
       pay, 
       sum(pay) over (order by date) as total
from the_table
order by date;
```

This assumes the `30` in the last line is just a typo and should actually be `300`

Answer (score 0):

These are portable ways to do it. I'm assuming that your dates are unique.

Inner join:

```
select t1."Date", min(t1.Pay) as Pay, sum(t1.Pay) as CumulativeTotal
from T t1 inner join T t2 on t2."Date" <= t1."Date"
group by t1."Date"
order by t1."Date"
```

Scalar subquery:

```
select
    t1."Date", t1.Pay,
    (select sum(Total) from T t2 where t2."Date" <= t1."Date") as CumulativeTotal
from T t1
order by t1."Date"
```

Comment: Works great but how do I specify for a particular client id?

Comment: forgot to mention for the inner join. Thanks!

Comment: Sounds like you add `and t2.Client = t1.Client`. Just a guess though. It would apply to both queries the same way too.